# Stepper motor for wire winding step calculations

Tags: stepper-motor, arduino-uno, stepper-driver

Stepper motor takes 200 steps/revolution without anything attached to the shaft. With a bobbin of 10mm in diameter and 50mm in length attached to stepper motor shaft, does it take the same 200 steps/loop of wire (0.5mm wire) for winding?

Comment: It's possible to put something on the shaft of a stepper that changes the number of steps it produces, but that's called 'stopping the stepper from working properly', or overloading it, and we try not to do it. Attach your load, and see whether the stepper has enough strength to turn it.

Answer (score 1):

The steps come from the mechanical construction, so it's 200 steps/revolution no matter what the load is.

If you drive 200 steps and it doesn't rotate full rotation, it's skipping steps, but that needs to be avoided. Stepper motor drives need to be designed so that it doesn't skip steps.

You might find some driver circuits offering *microstepping*. If you want more resolution than 200 steps, you can use the same motor, but introduce microstepping by the driver, it will drive the motor so that the motor can be held between the steps. With microstepping you can use a 200-step motor and get a resolution of for example 400 / 800 / 1600 steps per rotation.

Answer (score 0):

If you rarely, but still importantly encounter a missed step do to some non-repeatable loading event, you can use a larger torque stepper motor, or possibly use a closed loop stepper and driver, which will automatically retry the missed step(s).